# Triggering ASPxGridView RowClick event and handling it on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have an ASPxGridView which populates some transactions.

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="grdCapTrans" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" Width="100%"   EnableRowsCache="false">
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

When its populated, I would like to give the user the liberty of selecting a row and view details of the clicked row. The details shall be displayed below the gridview in textboxes.

How can this be triggered and be handled on the server?

Comment: Try with this demo: [Switch to the edit mode by clicking a status bar button or by double-clicking a row](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E7.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RowCommand event`

Link:http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_RowCommandtopic

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="grid" 
runat="server" 
ClientInstanceName="grid" 
AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
onrowcommand="grid_RowCommand" >
   <Columns>
     <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowSelectCheckbox="true" VisibleIndex="0" ButtonType="Button" />
   </Columns>
 </dx:ASPxGridView>
```

Code Behind :

```
 protected void grid_RowCommand(object sender, ASPxGridViewRowCommandEventArgs e)
 {
    ..... 
 }
```

Bind of your datas

```
grid.DataSource = ...;
grid.DataBind();
```

Link: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_RowDeletingtopic

Comment: I tried but I am not getting the data from the database.all I am getting is a checkbox on each row. I would like it to use data that is bound at runtime.

Comment: grid.DataSource = ...;
grid.DataBind();

Comment: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_RowDeletingtopic

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
     <Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="cboTransType"   EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
     </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
        <dx:ASPxGridView ID="grdCapTrans" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" Width="100%" EnableRowsCache="false" ClientInstanceName="grdCapTrans" onselectionchanged="grdCapTrans_SelectionChanged" 
        EnableCallBacks="false" KeyFieldName="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false"> 
        <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="0" ButtonType="Button" ShowSelectCheckbox="true"> </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ID" Name="ID" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="1"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Description" Name="Description" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="2"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Amount" Name="Amount" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="5"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn> 
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Date" Name="Date" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="4"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>   
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Capturer" Name="Capturer" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="3"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>                                                                                    
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Status" Name="Status" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="6"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>                                                                                                                                                               

        </Columns>
        <SettingsBehavior ProcessSelectionChangedOnServer="true"  AllowFocusedRow="true" AllowSelectByRowClick="true" EnableRowHotTrack="true"    />

        </dx:ASPxGridView>
        <p>
        </p>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void grdCapTrans_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

{ 

    UpdatePanel1.Update();
    txtFullName.Text = grdCapTrans.GetSelectedFieldValues("Description")[1].ToString();

    message.InnerHtml = "Happy";


}
```

The message element is a div which is found in a updatepanel1. I am expecting the message "Happy" to be displayed if selectionChanged event fires. To My surprise, It does not.

Whats wrong and how can that be corrected.

Comment: Read [ASPxGridView.SelectionChanged Event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_SelectionChangedtopic) and  [ASPxGridView.FocusedRowChanged Event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_FocusedRowChangedtopic). By the way, you should update your initial question instead of answering with something that isn't an answer. What is your motive for using UpdatePanel when only control inside it is ASPxGridView? Have you read article from my comment on initial question?

Comment: Filip, I am just trying out things. I am new to ASP.NET. By posting something thats not an answer was like to show what I have done so far. I have read the documents, but oops I cant make it either, I have googled alot of staff, but all in vain.